# Improving quality of questions asking for High Resolution?

Tags: discussion

Many questions are asked that say along the lines of,  "I would like to do x or y in high-resolution" or even worse, "I would like to obtain x or y in **very** high-resolution".

[Sample questions from search on `high resolution`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22high+resolution%22+is%3Aquestion)

It almost always indicates a low quality question. Not always but mostly. It is quite a meaningless statement. Some of the oceanographers I know consider 9 km data high resolution whereas lidar analysts working at the field level consider anything > 1 m low-resolution. This is rampant in GIS academic papers as well and is widely misused at best and intentionally misleading at worse.

How do people feel about first commenting and then downvoting questions that state high-resolution and ask them to specify the resolution?

Answer (score 3):

Although the sample questions include many that are not tagged [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) I think more of them should be tagged that way.

I think many, but far from all, [data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data) questions asked here are low quality.  I think this when they seem to be asked from the position of "I bet someone on GIS SE already knows the answer to this, so to save me researching first, and letting them know where I've looked, I'll just ask them to suggest sources for X data".

I support your position of using a strategy of commenting and downvoting to encourage more details of precisely what resolution they are looking for.  I also note that, since asking this question, you have attained the close voting privilege, and with that I will encourage you to consider voting to close as "unclear what you are asking" in preference, but sometimes in addition, to downvoting.

Comment: Yes the last part, "I support your position of using a strategy of commenting and downvoting to encourage more details of precisely what resolution they are looking for."